# javascript. formatting console.log

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

I´m working on a big angular.js project.

Now, I´ve to profile some pages about the performance.

With the console.log of the project I´m looking for the performance problems.

I miss if console.log can output the current time (yes, I know in Chrome you can set up).

Is there a way (like in log4java) to format  the output?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you just want to output the time as log or do you want to have the time besides each logged message?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, the `console` object should not be activated in production mainly because it can breaks the code for some users (for example IE8 or less users).

But if you want to test on a tool that you know, you can use the Web API interface which provides some useful method on this object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console

(This doc is from the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) and therefore mainly applies to Firefox, but at the end of that page you can find links to the corresponding docs for the IE, Chrome and Safari DevTools as well as Firebug).

For example, you can use the [`time()`](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console.time) method for your use case:

```
console.time("answer time");
// ... some other code
console.timeEnd("answer time");
```

Outputs something like this:

[image: Timing output in Firefox DevTools console]

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
console = window.console ? console : {};
native_log = console.log;
window.console.log = function myConsole() {
    // Cannot log if console.log is not present natively,
    // so fail silently (in IE without debugger opened)
    if (!native_log)
        return;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    args.unshift(new Date());
    native_log.apply(console, args);
}

console.log('hello'); // Date 2014-12-02T14:14:50.138Z "hello"
```

Of course, you would not let the new Date() as is, but it gives you the idea.

Comment: This advice works me only on ie. But as a mentioned before ie is the case I need to study. So this answer is very good for me.

Comment: I updated my answer to make it work also in Firefox and Chrome. And the output is also better, now.